# How to start a Podman pod and wait for termination of _all_ containers while multiplexing output of each?

Tags: shell, containers, podman

I have created a Podman pod to which I am adding new containers:

```bash
pod=$(podman pod create)
foo=$(podman create --pod $pod foo)
bar=$(podman create --pod $pod bar)
```

I then may "start" the pod with:

```bash
podman pod start $pod
```

...but I would like the shell or the `podman` process above to *wait* until the principal container ("foo" in the example) terminates, including on a Ctrl+C, or, alternatively *all* of the containers in the pod terminate.

I would also ideally prefer both "stderr" and "stdout" of each of the containers in the pod to be output in the terminal, *multiplexed*.

Is what I am asking for possible? I have looked at some of the options like `--interactive`, `--tty` and `--attach` but these seem to concern *different* Podman sub-commands (e.g. `pod`, `pod create`, `start`, `run` etc) and I can't seem to make sense of how these apply exactly and how to combine them to get the effect I want.

I have a script I can encapsulate some of the logic required to accomplish my wants, so if Podman alone can't be made to wait on pods (which I know it can with `podman run -it ...`, which I've done it before) or multiplex output of multiple containers, perhaps some shell magic, using redirection and file handles and what not, can help accomplish this?

Comment: It does feel like it should be fairly straightforward until you actually try to do it. I'm not seeing any obvious way either. Sorry that's not more helpful